# FrontEnd doesnt send httpOnly cookies

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt, cookie-httponly

I send httpOnly Cookies to my frontend as following

```
res.cookie('refreshToken', tokens.refreshToken, {
                httpOnly: true,
                secure:process.env.NODEENV ==='DEV'?false:true,
                expires:new Date(Date.now() + 24*30*60*60*1000 )})
            res.cookie('accessToken', tokens.accessToken, {
                httpOnly: true,
                secure: process.env.NODEENV ==='DEV'?false:true,
                expires: new Date(Date.now()+ 15*60*1000)
            })
            res.send()
```

My front end is on another domain but I enabled cors policy using cors package but for some reason the cookies aren't sent back to my backend in following requests. I found this out since I tried printing out cookies send from my frontend.

```
console.log(req.cookies )
```

I have been searching for two days but didn't find any useful information, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you making ajax request?

Comment: axios.get(url)
          .then(res => {
                if(res.status===200)
                {
                    this.setState({status:"connected"}) 
                    this.setState({user: res.data})
                }else{
                    const msg=responseHandler(res);

                }
            }).catch(err => {


            })

Comment: This is my code in frontend i assume the access Token should be send from the front end to authenticate the user but nothing is set